# TinyMCE editor not working in .NET web project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, nuget-package

I am attempting to use TinyMCE to use my TextArea control as a html editor while keeping the same ng-model data bindings I have been using. I have imported the most recent version of the package in the project and my script should be written correctly according to the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dotnet-projects/). Is there something that I am missing here?  [image: Script Location][image: [![Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS68j.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS68j.png)][image: Nuget packages][image: Result]

I have also Tried moving my script to different locations such as: Head tag of file, button of file, and script section of the shared layout. I was expecting to get a HTML editor element as shown in the Documentation of TinyMCE.

[image: Page Warnings/Issues]

Answer (score 0):

It might be the absolute pathway set with `~/Scripts/TinyMCE/...`. The docs say `src="/path/or/uri/to/tinymce.min.js"`, without specifying absolute or relative, but adding the complete pathway might help?